# How display different Grid from the control clicked?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Sorry for misleading title, I'll try to explain it better, suppose that I've this situation:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="1" />
            <TabItem Header="2" />
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
        <StackPanel Visibility="Hidden">
            <Button Content="1"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Visibility="Visible">
            <Button Content="2"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Now my goal is: when the user click on `TabItem` with `header = 1`, the `StackPanel` with button `content = 1` should be display, and also when the user click on `TabItem = 2`, the button with `content = 2` should be displayed.

Actually I know how can I do this behind code (c#), but is possible manage this only in wpf?

Comment: Why don't you use the `TabControl` how it is supposed to be used, i.e. putting the tab contents inside the `TabItems`? (Is this an oversimplification and you really need to do this manually?)

Comment: @H.B. 'cause I need to have the button outside the TabControl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options.

The quickest and dirtiest for the given example would be to trigger on the selected item `Header` of the `TabControl`:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
    <TabControl Name="tc">
        <TabItem Header="1" />
        <TabItem Header="2" />
    </TabControl>
</Grid>

<Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
    <Button Content="1">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=tc, Path=SelectedItem.Header}"
                                 Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
    <Button Content="2">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=tc, Path=SelectedItem.Header}"
                                 Value="2">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

(Default visibility needs to be in the `Setter` due to precedence.)

---

A cleaner/more modular solution would be to have a backing view-model that encapsulates the button logic and appearance and then bind the data of the button section to the selected item's button view-model. The button would then be created via [data templating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Is possible display the full stackpanel content? Perphaps I should change only the target, right? If I've as TabItem.Header an Image control this doesn't working

Comment: @IlDrugo: You'll need to wrap it inside a `ContentControl` or the like, panels have no `Style ` property, then you need to just move the style there, changing the `TargetType`.

Comment: if the Header contains only an image control? There is another trick?

Comment: You could set the `Tag` and trigger on that, but as i said, a view-model structure would be preferable.

Comment: I just noticed that `StackPanels` do have a `Style`, so you don't need a wrapper, had that mixed up with some other control.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply name the controls like:

```
<Stackpanel x:Name="spCon1" ../>
```

And then just trigger the event on TabControl, something like Selection changed....